# React Native nextFocusRight Prop on an TouchableOpacity is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to stop focus propagating from the last element in React Native using nextFocusRight but still, the focus propagates to the next view. According to this [pull](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/22082) request, it should be working but still, I'm facing the same issue

My code:
App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      data.push(i);

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {[1, 2].map(() => (
            <ScrollView horizontal style={{ height: 210 }}>
              {data.map(i => <Item id={i} buttonRef={this.buttonRef} />)}
            </ScrollView>
          ))}

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Item.js

```
export default class Item extends Component {
    myRef = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props;
        if (id == 0) {
            this.myRef.setNativeProps({ nextFocusLeft: findNodeHandle(this.myRef) })
        } else if (id == 9) {
            this.myRef.setNativeProps({ nextFocusRight: findNodeHandle(this.myRef) })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={id}
                ref={(c) => this.myRef = c}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'grey',
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 60 }}>{id}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

}
```

What is wrong here? Does anybody knows?

Comment: I don't think it could be the issue, but you should write triple equality check `id === 0` and `id === 9`

Comment: The issue seems to have fixed in 0.60. I can still reproduce this issue in 0.59.9. They have released 0.60 yesterday and the above code works @colinux

Comment: Just curious to ask what is nextFocusRight and nextFocusRight?

Comment: These props are for TV Focus control. You can take a look at the pull mentioned in the question for the issue and the solution. @AshwinMothilal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday React-Native released 0.60.0 fixing this bug. It's not mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but they have fixed it in 0.60.0.

For those of you who are using 0.59.9 or lesser, please upgrade your project to 0.60.0.